# Getting the number of push notifications received?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I've been learning about the push notifications on Windows Phone 7, and I was searching for a way to know how many Toast notifications a certain app got.

For example: Between 5 PM and 7 PM, my app would receive 7 Toast notifications when the user opens the app. It would display somewhere that it got those 7 notifications (and if possible the time and content of them).

Is this possible, and if so, how?

I've searched for some tutorials on this but all I find is the send and receive tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

If wp7 receive toast notification and user doesnt tap on it, toast notification just disappear.

So answer on your question is : NOT POSSIBLE.

Idea: you can create something like "confirmation request". When user tap on notification, you can send info to server. When user doesnt tap on notification I recommend use TILE notification...you can display number of unconfirmed notifications...and when user run app you can download all unconfirmed notifications's data.

Comment: i see.
can you point me to a tutorial or something showing how that is made?

much appreciated

Comment: I use something like that in my last project. We develop app to iOS and WP7 so we should fit server for both of them. 
But I dont have any specific tutorial.